# How to change the color of a png?

Tags: colors, png, kineticjs, tint

I am trying to change the color of a simple png. The png holds just a simple shape with transparency. At the moment I am changing the color via canvas context:

```
var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
var data = imageData.data;


for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    data[i] = Kinetic.Util.getRGB(color).r;
    data[i + 1] = Kinetic.Util.getRGB(color).g;
    data[i + 2] = Kinetic.Util.getRGB(color).b;
}

// overwrite original image
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

In firefox it takes some time to render the canvas. So is there any other solution?

Regards,
Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be a hell of a lot faster if you put this before the loop:

```
var col = Kinetic.Util.getRGB(color);
```

Then used this in the loop:

```
data[i] = col.r;
data[i+1] = col.g;
data[i+2] = col.b;
```